# Will removing Windows from my dual booted sytem(with Ubuntu) make my system faster?

Tags: dual-boot

I am not sure, but what I think is that my memory won't be allocated to Windows when not using Windows and hence that should not affect the processing power and the speed of Ubuntu.

So, to have my Ubuntu running more faster, should I remove Windows?

Comment: No. Removing Windows should not affect an Ubuntu installation in any way.

Comment: @mikewhatever Removing windows should mean that I will have more disk space than before, so even a larger disk space won't matter?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Disk space by itself is irrelevant, as long as there is enough free space. You can install Ubuntu on a small 32GB SSD, and it will be faster then when installed on a large, but slow 1TB HDD.